# Twitterkit TWTRComposer Crash

Tags: twitter, crash, twtrcomposer

I use TwitterKit to send tweet, use this code.

```
TWTRComposer *twitterComposer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
[twitterComposer setText:string];
[twitterComposer setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[twitterComposer setImage:image];
[twitterComposer showFromViewController:viewController completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
  if (result == TWTRComposerResultDone) {

  }else {

}
}];
```

but crash in code

```
[twitterComposer showFromViewController:viewController completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
```

I had get Twitter login session

use SLComposerViewController the same to crash

crash info :
Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <>

in ios 10.0.2

I can't find any answer in https://twittercommunity.com

Answer (score 2):

check session before call TWTRComposer.Otherwise app will crash.
try this:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession * _Nullable session, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (session) {
        TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
        [composer setText:@"just setting up my Fabric"];
        [composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fabric"]];
        [composer setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.toshow.com"]];
        [composer showFromViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {

        }];
    } else {
        [CustomToast makeToast:@"get session failed"];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Did it work? For me it didn't. It keeps saying "Assertion failure in -[NSLayoutConstraint _setMultiplier:]'" and "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Multiplier is not finite!  That's illegal.  multiplier:nan'"